# Is it possible to increase the speed of the .css method on the .scroll event?

Tags: jquery, performance

This is my code:

```
$( window ).scroll( function () {
    scrollBG( '#about' );
}

function scrollBG( e ) {
  bg_position = $( document ).scrollTop() / 2;
  $( e ).css( 'background-position-y', bg_position );
}
```

What it does is scroll the background of an element as the user scrolls.
This works fine, the only issue is when using the mousewheel to scroll, the css take a few milliseconds to catch up (since the mousewheel will move like 100px at a time).

Is there way to make the css change happen instantaneously?
Perhaps native JavaScript is faster?

I've noticed this plugin does not have the issue I'm facing, but I don't want to use it as it seems overkill for my needs: http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

Comment: You could use a throttle and possibly a delta check to avoid changing the css on every move and instead moving it every x ms and/or every z change in scroll position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no, scroll event is being fired only limited times per second. 
First of all - try setting background-attachment to fixed.
Second - it's better to use requestAnimationFrame whenever possible, rather than jQuery $(window).scroll method.

Comment: Simply setting the background-attachment property of the element to fixed does the trick! No longer jittery when scrolling with the mousewheel. :) I wonder why though? My function works in exactly the same way.. Anyway thanks

Comment: that's because when background-attachment is not set to fixed, while scrolling its position gets recalculated (and applied) by browser, and THEN new position is apllied, recalculated by your js.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts:

- Do you have other css rules on the element to maintain? If not setting the style property directly might be faster.
- As suggested by Kevin B in the comments, you could delay the actual shifting of the background, and possibly animate the shift in position to make the move less jarring.

Comment: I've tried the .style method but no difference.
Regarding delaying the css change, I can't do that - the change needs to happen at the exact same time.